# Что такое Debug в PyCharm

Tags: отладка, pycharm

Что такое Debug в PyCharm? И зачем оно нужно?

Comment: Правильно, отладка не нужна, принты - наше все. А если серьезно - [Отладка программы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Отладка_программы)

Comment: [Debugging Help PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging.html) Начните отсюда: [Part 1. Debugging Python Code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/part-1-debugging-python-code.html), Вам понравится! И, как правильно сказал @insolor, [Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging).